# displaying alert message in angular

Tags: angular, alert

I am using the ngx-alert service to display an error message if the credentials don' t correspond to a user account in my db.

This is what i did:

```
 if (this.check.data.length == 0) {
      this.alert.danger('User doesn\'\t exist');

        this.userForm.reset()
      }

      else {
       this.alert.success('You are going to be redirected');
        sessionStorage.setItem('user',this.check.data[0].username);
       setTimeout(this.router.navigate(['/home',{data:  'ok'}] ), 3000)
      }
```

When the user exists, the message is displayed correctly but after ther redirection with router.navigate is not working,
i get the following error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGF5I.png)

i don' t understand this error, i don't see when i am calling the Object()

Thanks you for your help

Comment: which line is `user.component.ts:77` ?

Comment: Also, please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue.

Comment: the line 77 is :  this.alert.success('You are going to be redirected');

Comment: The it's a library error.

Comment: so i may check the version of the librairy?

Comment: Why You used setTimeout here?

Comment: Rather create an issue in thei repository. Be sure that you don't have effed up anything by creating a [mcve] to show the issue.

Comment: well i wanted to display the message and then 3 sec later make the redirection

Answer (score 1):

Looks Like this statement is not correct

```
  setTimeout(this.router.navigate(['/home',{data:  'ok'}] ), 3000)
```

Use it Like:

```
setTimeout(()=> {this.router.navigate(['/home',{data:  'ok'}] )}, 3000)
```